Создание общей папки для виртуальной машины и обычного компа
На диске C создал папку SharedFolder , в параметры виртуальной машины добавил эту папку, но в разделе network виртуалки она не отображается, как это исправить?  

В самой виртуалке попробуйте в сетевом окружении посмотреть

В виртуалке в Network and Sharing center включил Turn on network discovery, но в network все равно не отображается папка. Служба Function Discovey Resource Publication включена

Разобрался, проблема решилась установкой vmware tools внутри виртуальной машины

Ну понятно тогда, в virtualbox похоже работает, там нужно установить в виртуалке guest additions, тогда все дополнительные функции типа общих папок начинают работать
